# how to type a promise that returns a retrieved stripe checkout session with expand?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, stripe-payments

Anybody knows how to type a promise that returns a retrieved stripe checkout session with expand?

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(event.data.object.id, {
      expand: ['line_items.data.price.product', 'customer'],
    })
```

So far this seems to get a long way

```js
const session: Stripe.Checkout.Session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
      event.data.object.id,
      {
        expand: ['line_items.data.price.product', 'customer'],
      }
    )

const { name, email, created  } = session.customer as Stripe.Customer
const line_items = session.line_items.data

const {} = line_items[0]
```

[image: vscode example]

`line_items.data.price.product` is not typed

Comment: I'd go for `const session: Stripe.Checkout.Session & { customer: Stripe.Customer; line_items: … } = …`. But I doubt you can write a type that does this automatically based on the `expand` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
const getSessionWithCustomerAndLineItems = async () => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve("mockId", {
    expand: ["line_items.data.price.product", "customer"],
  });

  const customer = session.customer as Stripe.Customer;

  // Type is Stripe.LineItem[]
  const line_items = session.line_items.data;

  // Infers return type as:
  // Stripe.Response<Stripe.Checkout.Session> & {
  //   customer: Stripe.Customer,
  //   line_items: Stripe.LineItems[],
  // }
  return Object.assign(session, { customer, line_items });
};
```

The key thing to note is that the stripe-node docs specifically call out using 'expand' with TypeScript requires explicit casting in the result: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#using-expand-with-typescript

Given the product portion of your expand statement, you might also want to include a Products array directly in the output:

```
const getSessionWithCustomerAndProducts = async () => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve("mockId", {
    expand: ["line_items.data.price.product", "customer"],
  });

  const customer = session.customer as Stripe.Customer;

  // Type is Stripe.Product[]
  const products =
    session.line_items?.data.map(
      ({ price }) => price.product as Stripe.Product
    ) ?? [];

  // Infers return type as:
  // Stripe.Response<Stripe.Checkout.Session> & {
  //   customer: Stripe.Customer,
  //   products: Stripe.Product[],
  // }
  return Object.assign(session, { customer, products });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`line_items.data.price.product` won't be typed since `Product` has three types, with `string` as the first one:https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/types/2020-08-27/Prices.d.ts#L64

You can still do what you want, it just requires some extra steps as you have to tell TypeScript exactly which type it should be using:

```
const line_items: Stripe.LineItem[] = session.line_items?.data as Stripe.LineItem[];
const {price}: {price: Stripe.Price} = line_items[0] as Stripe.LineItem;  
const product: Stripe.Product = price.product as Stripe.Product;

// product will now be typed
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but the returned session object contains the customer's and the product's ID. You can use these IDs to fetch details for the customer and product with the respective API.

Comment: The returned session is giving me want I want - I just have a hard time getting typescript to understand that this is not a standard stripe session type - but an expanded version